# Brownian Bridge - Multiple Paths

Tags: list-manipulation

I am attempting to simulate multiple [Brownian Bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) on the interval `[0, 1]`. I have the following snippet:

```
t = 100;  
dt = 1/t;  
paths = 5;  
bm[n_] := Accumulate[Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, dt], n], 0]]  
b = Table[bm[t], {paths}];   
b1 = b[[All, -1]];
```

This code creates a table (`b`) with multiple paths of a random walk and then takes the last value (`b1`) of each path. I'm now trying to create a table with data for Brownian Bridges, but am at a complete loss. I know that I need to subtract `1/t*b1` from each element in each of the random walks, but can't find any information on how to do this in *Mathematica*.

Appreciate any help that can be provided.

Note: I'm trying to do this without using the `BrownianBridgeProcess` function.

Comment: Try `list-1/t*b1`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've explained this well enough. I need to subtract '(1/t)*b1' from the first element of each process, '(2/t)*b1' from the second element etc...

Comment: Well, okay, one of the easiest ways is to create a `Table` from those values and just subtract it from the respective Brownian process' table of values

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, does not work when cut-n-pasted, please fix. In any case, I think you're after `b - (Range[0, t]/t*#) & /@ b1;` (it's not clear what you want as "first" element - the first generated, or the 0 prepended, so adjust range accordingly.) Any reason you're not using the built-in `BrownianBridgeProcess`?

Comment: Sorry @ciao, new to this. Should work with cut/paste now. Thanks for the code suggestion, but it creates objects of unequal length. I'll try the suggestion of creating a 'Table', I guess using iterations?

Comment: Sorry, prior was written guessing at what you meant output to be. With your fixed code, `b - ((Range[0, t]/t*#) & /@ b1)` ( again, check range to fit needs) - s/b *much* faster than using table.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Ciao, that's perfect.